# How to load column of datatype Varchar to other table of column datatype Date in sql when it is primary key

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert column which is of data type varchar and it is primary key .Now i need to convert into date data type which has multiple dates (mmddyy) while loading from other column in sql server.

To be clear I created Table B has Column DTB  which is date datatype and is primary key now i want to load data into this column DTB from Table A column DTA which is varchar and here the records are of form 12717(mm/dd/yy) 20k records need to be loaded of such different dates.

can you please help me in converting.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you give us some sample data

Comment: Didn't getting what you actually wants to do?

Comment: Your DTA `'12717'` does not have 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The right date format style of "mm/dd/yy" is `1` for the `convert` function

```
SELECT convert(date, '01/15/18', 1)
```

Now you can insert data into table B from A

```
INSERT INTO tableB (DTB, ...)
SELECT convert(date, DTA, 1) AS DTB, ... FROM tableA
```